# Definition of a formula in propositional logic

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

The set of formulae in propositional logic is characterised by ( at least in Derek Goldreis's book)

1. Every propositional variable is a formula
2. If $a$ is a formula then so is $\neg a$
3. If $a,b$ are formulae then so are $(a \star b)$ for any connective $\star$
4. Nothing else is a formula and every formula is obtained by a finite number of applications of 1)-3).

From this, does it immediately follow that for any formula $a$ exactly one of the following holds

1') $a$ is some propositional variable

2') $a$ is $\neg b$ for some formula $b$

3') $a$ is $(b \star c)$ for some formulae $b,c$?

I know this is true ( infact the stronger Unique readability theorem holds) but it isn't clear to me how this immediately follows from the definition of a formula I gave above.

I suspect it is clause 4) that makes this work. So perhaps my question really is what exactly does clause 4) mean...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does follow immediately, and yes, it is the fourth clause that makes this work.

The fourth clause says that every formula is the result of applying the first three clauses a finite number of times. In particular, any formula $a$ is the result of applying one of the first three clauses to existing formulae. If $a$ results from (1), $a$ must be a propositional variable. If it results from (2), it must be $\neg b$ for some formula $b$ that has already been derived. And if it results from (3), it must be $(b*c)$ for some connective $*$ and formulae $b$ and $c$ that have already been derived.

This is a fairly straightforward recursive definition of the set of formulae. The first clause is the base clause: it defines the propositional variables as formulae and so gives us some input for the construction clauses (2) and (3) that define how more complex formulae are to be built from simpler ones. And the fourth clause, which is often omitted but should always be understood, prevents us from throwing random junk into the collection of formulae: every formula *must* be a propositional variable or derivable from propositional variables by applications of (2) and (3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful to me. So it seems to me that ( as I believe you wrote) clause 4) says that a formula is a finite application of 1)-3) so in particular it is *a* application of 1)-3) and this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ansdfkjdasnflkj: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd interpret "nothing else is a formula" as meaning what you concluded: that every formula is of one of the three given forms. I don't think the "exactly one" part technically follows, but it's implied. We can think of the set of formulas as an [inductive type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type) whose elements are [syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Comment: Thanks ( I'd upvote if I had the reputation to do so)! This is much as I thought and the exactness part wasn't really important for my question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to a lot of interesting general concepts. Brian Scott outlines the simple answer. I will go a bit deeper into the theory of inductively defining a subset.

For some background, consider a set $A$ and a function $f : P(A) \to P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is the powerset of $A$. Suppose that $f$ is monotonic - that is, if $K \subseteq J \subseteq A$ then $f(K) \subseteq f(J)$.

In this case, $f$ must have a "least fixed point". That is, there must be some $K \in P(A)$ such that $f(K) = K$ and for every $J$, if $f(J) = J$ then $K \subseteq J$.

This least fixed point is constructed by defining $K = \cap \{J \subseteq A | f(J) \subseteq J\}$. For consider the set $f(K)$, and consider an arbitrary set $J \subseteq A$ such that $f(J) \subseteq J$. Then we have $K \subseteq J$, and thus $f(K) \subseteq f(J) \subseteq J$. Therefore, we must have $f(K) \subseteq K$. But since $f(K) \subseteq K$, we also have $f(f(K)) \subseteq f(K)$. And therefore, $K \subseteq f(K)$. Thus, we see that $f(K) = K$, and $K$ is indeed a fixed point.

And clearly, if we have any $J$ such that $J = f(J)$, then we in particular have $f(J) \subseteq J$ and therefore $K \subseteq J$. So $K$ is indeed the "least fixed point" of $f$.

Let's discuss how this applies to the definition of formulas. Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \{(, ), \neg\} \cup B \cup V$, where $B$ is the set of binary operators and $V$ is the set of variables.

We then define the set $\Sigma^*$ to be the set of all finite sequences with elements in $\Sigma$. We abusively write $V \subseteq \Sigma^*$ to be the set of one-element sequences where the single element is a variable.

Now given a set $U \subseteq \Sigma^*$, define $f(U) = V \cup \{\neg \phi | \phi \in U\} \cup \{(\phi * \psi) | \phi, \psi \in U, * \in B\}$. We see that $f : P(\Sigma^*) \to P(\Sigma^*)$ is an increasing function. Therefore, $f$ has a least fixed point.

That least fixed point is the set of all formulas. Call the least fixed point $K$.

What do we know about $K$? We know that $K = V \cup \{\neg \phi | \phi \in K\} \cup \{(\phi * \psi) | \phi, \psi \in K, * \in B\}$. It follows immediately that every formula can be written as $a$ for $a \in V$, or as $\neg \phi$ for some formula $\phi$, or as $(\phi * \psi)$ for formulas $\phi, \psi$ and binary operator $* \in B$.

We also have the following "induction principle" for $K$. Consider a predicate $P$. Suppose that for all $v \in V$, $P(v)$. Suppose also that if $P(\phi)$, we then have $P(\neg \phi)$. And finally, suppose that if $P(\phi)$ and $P(\psi)$, and if we have $* \in B$, then $P((\phi * \psi))$ holds. Then for every formula $\xi \in K$, $P(\xi)$ holds.

How do we know this? Consider the set $J = \{\xi \in \Sigma^* | P(\xi)\}$. Then $f(J) \subseteq J$. Then $K \subseteq J$.

It turns out that this induction principle, together with the fact that $f(K) \subseteq K$, uniquely characterises $K$. This is the basis of the theory of recursive definitions of a subset and the corresponding principles of induction.

Interestingly, there is another way to define $K$ in this case. It can be shown that $K = \bigcup\limits_{n = 0}^\infty f^n(\emptyset)$. Intuitively, $f^n(\emptyset)$ is the set of all formulas which can be formed using rules 1-3 with a depth of at most $n$. This is the justification for rule 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had to give it a careful read, but it's very helpful to me. If I had the reputation I'd upvote!